# Replicating excel calculation in python dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I am trying to replicate this excel calculation `=C2*A3^B3` in python dataframe. But not able to get the calculated field of the previous row into my calculation.

[image: Excel data]

[image: formuls]

Input Data :

```
 ftax        stax
 1.000000000     0   
 0.999959316     3   
 0.999959316     1   
 0.999959316     3   
 0.999959316     3   
 0.999959316     1
```

If I put the Values in excel and apply this formula I get below result and wanted to replicate the same in python

`=C2*A3^B3` in cell C3 and  `=A2^B2`in Cell C2

Desired Output :

```
ftax         stax   cal_field
1.000000000  0      1.000000000
0.999959316  3      0.999877952
0.999959316  1      0.999837272
0.999959316  3      0.999715244
0.999959316  3      0.999593230
0.999959316  1      0.999552562
```

Sample code which I tried

```
nav_df = pd.DataFrame(nav_cal)
nav_df[cal_filed_1] = nav_df[cal_filed].shift(1).fillna("1")

print (nav_df[cal_filed]*(nav_df[cal_filed_1])**nav_df[9]) #I think this is not the right way
```

And I am getting below Output:

```
      ftax     stax cal_field
0     0.999996   0  1.000000  
1     0.999996   3  0.999837  
2     0.999996   1  0.999919  
3     0.999996   3  0.999837  
4     0.999996   3  0.999837  
5     0.999996   1  0.999919
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need [`cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html), only is necessary first value is always `1`:

```
df['cal_field'] = (df['ftax'] ** df['stax']).cumprod()
print (df)
       ftax  stax  cal_field
0  1.000000     0   1.000000
1  0.999959     3   0.999877
2  0.999959     1   0.999836
3  0.999959     3   0.999713
4  0.999959     3   0.999590
5  0.999959     1   0.999549
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for the quick answer but I got only two input columns and have to get the cal_field I have modified my question

Comment: @Abhis - answer was edited, always first value is `1` ?

Comment: yes it’s always 1 as the first row of stax will be always 0. Thanks much I was breaking my head for hours.